# How to rewrite if argument is not numeric with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a script with a query with an id parameter that must be numeric.
If the argument is not only numeric, it should use the numeric part and redirect.

for exemple, if i have this url :
    example.com/test.php?id=45sdfdsfsdfsdf
it should redirect to :
    example.com/test.php?id=45

of course, i do it with an int in the php code but i would like the url to be corrected.

```
   if ($arg_id = ([\d]+).+) {
        return 301 $uri?id=$1;
    }
```

I have tried rewrite to with instead of return 301 :

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$uri?id=$1;
```

Comment: You need to use a regular expression operator `~` or `~*`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for details. And you probably need the regular expression to match at least one non-digit character, for example: `([\d]+)[^\d]`

Comment: Brilliant ! It's working ! Thanks a million. So, the full working code is now :     if ($arg_id ~ ([\d]+)[^\d]) {
        return 301 $uri?id=$1;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following response from Richard, the answer :

```
if ($arg_id ~ ([\d]+)[^\d]) {
    return 301 $uri?id=$1; 
}
```